# When i click in logout button open a confirm alert. When i cancel it will redirect login page but i want to redirect current page. How i can do it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In My react application. When i click logout button. it open a confirm alert. if i confirm it i will logout from my application. whenever i cancel it it also redirect to my login route. **I want the route will be the same when i will cancel it.** How can i do it? My code is:

[Code Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qv1x.png)
[Client Site Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWGZg.png)

```
 const logOut = () => {
const confirm = window.confirm('Are you sure to logout?');
if (confirm) {
  signOut(auth)
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can add `else` statement for the required purpose. Following code demonstrate the purpose:

```js
const logout = () => {
    const confirm = window.confirm("are you sure?");
    if(confirm){
        window.location.href = "http://www.w3schools.com";
    }else {
        // same as clicking a link 
        // not optimal solution though
        window.location.href = window.location.href;
    }
}
```